# TypeError: _this2.categoryOptions.find is not a function

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a select option that will show the category when it's been saved. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting this error in my console

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _this2.categoryOptions.find is not a function"

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="addCategory" name="category">
            <option v-for="category in categoryOptions" :value="category.id">{{ category.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['product', 'categories'],
        data() {
            return {
                addCategory: null,
                categoryOptions: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {

            axios.get('/admin/products/'+this.product.id+'/category').then((response) => {
                this.categoryOptions = response.data;
            });
        },
        computed: {
            categoryOptions(){
                let options = [];

                options.push({id:0, text: "Please select one"});

                let filteredCategory = this.categories.filter(category => {
                    return this.categoryOptions.find(selected => categoryOptions.category_id === category.id) == null;
                });

                filteredCategory.forEach(sc => {
                    options.push({id: sc.id, text: sc.name});
                });

                return options;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
let filteredCategory = this.categories.filter(category => {
  return this.categoryOptions.find(selected => categoryOptions.category_id === category.id) == null;
});
```

per

```
let filteredCategory = this.categories.filter(category => {
  return this.categoryOptions.find(selected => selected.category_id === category.id) == null;
});
```

note that you just forgot to replace ***categoryOptions*** with ***selected***. But to ensure that the component is loaded, I advise you to make the `props` `categories` required, and ensure that it is persisted for the component before rendering.

```
 <script>
    export default {
        props: {
           'product',
            'categories': {
               type: [Array, Object],
               required: true,
            },
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Another tip if you use the chrome browser, is to use a very cool extension which is [Vue.js devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) to follow the status of your application.